# How to set a catch-all error handler?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there a way to set a catch-all error handler, like window.onerror, but in Chrome apps? I ask because window.onerror doesn't work. I found this [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382997) for extension which might explain why it doesn't work. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: My main reasons are 1) report the errors to my server/web analytics, so I will know if there are problems, specially fatal errors, after the app is published, and 2) let the user know an error has occurred (and ask him/her to let us know), that way its better than to fail silently in some cases.